# Disable commit button until it validates all number fields are valid

Tags: javascript, html

I have one html page with three number fields.

```css
function checkLength_minlen(elem) {
if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = 'Min 6 and Max 256';
    document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
else if (elem.value < 6) {
    document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Min value is 6";
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
  else if (elem.value > 256) {
    document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Max value is 256";
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Min 6 and Max 256";
   document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  }
}

function checkLength_expiry(elem) {
if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = 'Min 2 and Max 1024';
    document.getElementById("msg2").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
else if (elem.value < 2) {
    document.getElementById("msg2").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML="Min value is 2";
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
  else if (elem.value > 1024) {
    document.getElementById("msg2").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML="Max value is 1024";
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg2").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML="Min 2 and Max 1024";
   document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  }
}

function checkLength_history(elem) {
if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML = 'Min 1 and Max 32';
    document.getElementById("msg3").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
else if (elem.value < 1) {
    document.getElementById("msg3").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML="Min value is 1";
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
  else if (elem.value > 32) {
    document.getElementById("msg3").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML="Max value is 32";
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg3").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML="Min 1 and Max 32";
   document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Minlen">
<label class="heading">Minimum Length</label>
<input type="number" id="Minlen_text" min=6 max=256 onkeyup="checkLength_minlen(this)" value='8'> <span class="heading1" id="msg1"></span>
</div>
<div id="expiry">
<label class="heading">Expiry</label>
<input type="number" id="Expiry_text" min=2 max=1024 onkeyup="checkLength_expiry(this)" value='100'> <span class="heading1" id="msg2"></span>
</div>
<div id="history">
<label class="heading">History</label>
<input type="number" id="History_text" min=1 max=32 onkeyup="checkLength_history(this)" value='5'> <span class="heading1" id="msg3"></span>
</div>
<input type=submit class="commit" id="submit" value=Commit onclick="commit()">
```

Now my question is like the "Commit" button is getting disabled on wrong entry in the field one (Minlen) and when I switched to the second number field the "commit" button is getting enabled.
But I want the commit button to be disabled if any of the fields have out of range values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use three boolean variable to control validation of this three input. It's a very simple way to achieve your target. try this:

```js
var isValidMinLen=true;
var isValidExpiry=true;
var isValidHistory=true;
function checkLength_minlen(elem) {

if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = 'Min 6 and Max 256';
    document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidMinLen=false;
  }
else if (elem.value < 6) {
    document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Min value is 6";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidMinLen=false;
  }
  else if (elem.value > 256) {
    document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Max value is 256";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidMinLen=false;
  }
 else {
 debugger
   document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Min 6 and Max 256";
   isValidMinLen=true;
   checkButtonValidation();
  }
}

function checkLength_expiry(elem) {
if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = 'Min 2 and Max 1024';
    document.getElementById("msg2").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidExpiry=false;
  }
else if (elem.value < 2) {
    document.getElementById("msg2").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML="Min value is 2";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
     isValidExpiry=false;
  }
  else if (elem.value > 1024) {
    document.getElementById("msg2").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML="Max value is 1024";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
     isValidExpiry=false;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg2").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML="Min 2 and Max 1024";
   isValidExpiry=true;
   checkButtonValidation();
  }
}

function checkLength_history(elem) {
if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML = 'Min 1 and Max 32';
    document.getElementById("msg3").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidHistory=false;
  }
else if (elem.value < 1) {
    document.getElementById("msg3").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML="Min value is 1";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidHistory=false;
  }
  else if (elem.value > 32) {
    document.getElementById("msg3").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML="Max value is 32";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidHistory=false;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg3").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML="Min 1 and Max 32";
   isValidHistory=true;
   checkButtonValidation();
}
}
function checkButtonValidation(){
debugger
if(isValidMinLen==false || isValidExpiry==false || isValidHistory==false){
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
}else{
   document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="Minlen">
<label class="heading">Minimum Length</label>
<input type="number" id="Minlen_text" min=6 max=256 onkeyup="checkLength_minlen(this)" value='8'> <span class="heading1" id="msg1"></span>
</div>
<div id="expiry">
<label class="heading">Expiry</label>
<input type="number" id="Expiry_text" min=2 max=1024 onkeyup="checkLength_expiry(this)" value='100'> <span class="heading1" id="msg2"></span>
</div>
<div id="history">
<label class="heading">History</label>
<input type="number" id="History_text" min=1 max=32 onkeyup="checkLength_history(this)" value='5'> <span class="heading1" id="msg3"></span>
</div>
<input type=submit class="commit" id="btn" value=Commit onclick="commit()">
```